# Joining paths in Java

Tags: java

In `Python` I can join two paths with `os.path.join`:

```
os.path.join("foo", "bar") # => "foo/bar"
```

I'm trying to  achive the same in Java, without worrying if the `OS` is `Unix`, `Solaris` or `Windows`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
    String current_dir = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
    String filename = "data/foo.txt";
    Path filepath = currentRelativePath.resolve(filename);

    // "data/foo.txt"
    System.out.println(filepath);

}
```

I was expecting that `Path.resolve( )` would join my current directory `/home/user/test` with `data/foo.txt` making `/home/user/test/data/foo.txt`.
What am I getting wrong?

Comment: this might be something I'm not seeing. Your current path is "". Your second path is "data/foo.txt". Maybe your problem is you seem to be printing a Path object instead of `filepath.toString()`

Comment: Use ```new File(parent, child)```

Comment: N.B. `import java.nio.file.Paths;`

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Even though the original solution for getting the current directory using the `empty String` works. But is recommended to use the `user.dir` property for current directory and `user.home` for home directory.

```
Path currentPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
Path filePath = Paths.get(currentPath.toString(), "data", "foo.txt");
System.out.println(filePath.toString());
```

output:

```
/Users/user/coding/data/foo.txt
```

---

From Java [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) class Documentation:

> A Path is considered to be an empty path if it consists solely of one name element that is `empty`. Accessing a file using an `empty path is equivalent to accessing the default directory` of the file system.

---

**Why `Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath()` works**

When an empty string is passed to the `Paths.get("")`, the returned `Path` object contains empty path. But when we call `Path.toAbsolutePath()`, it checks whether path length is greater than zero, otherwise it uses `user.dir` system property and return the current path.

Here is the code for Unix file system implementation: [UnixPath.toAbsolutePath()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/nio/fs/UnixPath.java#UnixPath.toAbsolutePath%28%29)

---

Basically you need to create the `Path` instance again once you resolve the current directory path.

Also I would suggest using `File.separatorChar` for platform independent code.

```
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
Path currentDir = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath(); // <-- Get the Path and use resolve on it.
String filename = "data" + File.separatorChar + "foo.txt";
Path filepath = currentDir.resolve(filename);

// "data/foo.txt"
System.out.println(filepath);
```

Output:

```
/Users/user/coding/data/foo.txt
```

Comment: Not me, maybe someone think working on strings and `separatorChar` is inferior to some "higher level abstraction", something that looks like `PathBuilder(currentRelativePath).append("data").append("foo.txt")`

Comment: All these examples doesn't seem optimal: conversion from Path to String and again to Path

Answer (score 35):

[`Paths#get(String first, String... more)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)) states,

> Converts a path string, or a *sequence of strings* that when joined form a path string, to a `Path`.
>
> ...
>
> A [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) representing an *empty* path is returned if first is the empty
>   string and more does not contain any non-empty strings.

To get the current user directory you can simply use `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

```
Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "abc.txt");
System.out.println(path);
```

Moreover, `get` method uses [*variable length argument*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) of `String`, which will be used to provide subsequent path strings. So, to create `Path` for `/test/inside/abc.txt` you have to use it in a following way,

```
Path path = Paths.get("/test", "inside", "abc.txt");
```

Answer (score 13):

Not an specific method.

If you use java 8 or better, you have 2 options:

a) Use java.util.StringJoiner

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(File.pathSeparator); //Separator
joiner.add("path1").add("path2");
String joinedString = joiner.toString();
```

b) Use `String.join(File.pathSeparator, "path1", "path2");`

If you use java 7 or lower, you may use commons-lang library from apache commons. The class StringUtils has a method to join strings using a separator.

c) `StringUtils.join(new Object[] {"path1", "path2"}, File.pathSeparator);`

A sidenote: You may use linux pathseparator "/" for windows (Just remember that absolute paths are something like "/C:/mydir1/mydir2". Using always "/" is very useful if you use protocols such as file://

Comment: StringJoiner returned me `/home/user/test:foo.txt`

Comment: The options you know of aren't the only ones in existence. One could use StringBuilder instead of joiner, for example. And in fact, your implementation based on Strings rather than files/paths is quite naive and would lead to problems in many scenarios.

Comment: `File.separator` worked for me instead of `File.pathSeparator`

Comment: use Pathes.get("path1", "path2").toAbsolutePath().toString()

Answer (score 7):

You can do like

```
// /root
Path rootPath = Paths.get("/root");
// /root/temp
Path temPath = rootPath.resolve("temp");
```

A good detailed post is here [Path Sample Usecase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html)

Comment: It works only if argument of resolve doesn't start with "/"

Answer (score 6):

The most basic way is:

```
Path filepath = Paths.get("foo", "bar");
```

You should never write `Paths.get("")`.  I'm surprised that works at all.  If you want to refer to the current directory explicitly, use `Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"))`.  If you want the user's home directory, use `Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"))`.

You can also combine the approaches:

```
Path filepath = Paths.get(
    System.getProperty("user.home"), "data", "foo.txt");
```

Answer (score 5):

For Java >= 11 the recommended way now is to use [Path.of](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) instead of [Paths.get](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)), as suggested by previous answers. Quoting from Java 11 [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html):

> It is recommended to obtain a Path via the Path.of methods instead of via the get methods defined in this class as this class may be deprecated in a future release.

E.g., the following will join "foo" and "bar", according to the OS path separator:

```java
import java.nio.file.Path;
...

Path fooBar = Path.of("foo", "bar");
```

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable, platform-independent way to join paths in Java is by using `Path::resolve` (as noted in the JavaDoc for [`Paths::get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-)). For an arbitrary-length array of Strings representing pieces of a path, these could be joined together using a Java Stream:

```
private static final String[] pieces = {
    System.getProperty("user.dir"),
    "data",
    "foo.txt"};
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Path dest = Arrays.stream(pieces).reduce(
    /* identity    */ Paths.get(""),
    /* accumulator */ Path::resolve,
    /* combiner    */ Path::resolve);
    System.out.println(dest);
}
```